# Multiple resource control Keycloak

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak, software-design

I'm developing one POC, but can't understand how protect some resource for multiple users and 
 accounts in Keycloak

I have two users: `bob` and `ana`.

`bob` has `EDIT` permission to access accountId: `123`, `234`

`ana` has `VIEW` permission to access accountId: `123`, `555` 
(In future it can have more than 10k accounts and users)

When users access `/accounts/{accountId}` I need know if user have permission on `{accountId}` and if they can `VIEW` or `EDIT` this page.

I think create User Attribute named `allowed_accounts` in each user, and Roles for `VIEW` and `EDIT`, but I think this is not the correct way to do this.

Can someone help me how can I model this on KeyCloak?

Answer (score 0):

One option is, each account could be modeled as a resource and then add resource attributes. Use those attributes while evaluating the permissions

like `edit-users` and `view-users`, you can get more information from the keycloak [authorization](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#resource-attributes) documentation

[image]